# Jquery: get the inputs only of submitted form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have multiple forms in a page. I need get only the inputs children of the submitted form.

This is my code (of course it doesn't function).

```
    $('form.modal-form').on('submit',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_errors = 0;
        $(this).children('input.required-field').each(function(index) 
        {
            [....]   
   });
});
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Where is your html? What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [$.fn.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead of [$.fn.children](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which only gets direct children:

```
$(this).find('input.required-field').each(function(index) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Btw, `$(this).find('input.required-field')` is equivalent to `$('input.required-field', this)` so choose whatever you prefer more to your taste.

Comment: @eisbehr Well, this is what happens in this case: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/core/init.js#L94

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements inside a `context`. This is the second parameter after the selector of the jQuery function. Passing `this` in there let jQuery search for your selector only in this `context`, which will give you just the elements you are looking for ...

```
$('form.modal-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('input.required-field', this).each(function() {
        // do your work
    });
});
```

Your used `children` may not work here, because this function would only search one node deeper for your selector. You could switch from `.children()` to `.find()`, what should do the work.

But I would still prefer to use a context selector!